# Dataset of Tweets by Same User

Tags: keras, dataset

I was reading the Keras documentation on shared layers, and used the example of a model built to classify whether 2 tweets were from the same user or not.  Is there any dataset that I could use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find great datasets for this task called author verification from the PAN workshop series. Afaik the last one specifically on this task was in 2015: https://pan.webis.de/clef15/pan15-web/author-identification.html. I recommend exploring the website, there are many other datasets for related tasks.